# Custom choiceType field

Tags: symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

Please, help me!

I'm trying to make a form for a product with colors. Colors are objects in database.

```
$builder
    ->add('product')
    ->add('colors', 'choice', 
        array(
            // $colors is array of objects [id: {id: 1, name: "red", "img": "pic_path"} 
            'choices'  => $colors, 
            'expanded' => true
        )
    )
;
```

I'd like to get a form with custom radio-inputs, containing name and picture from Color-object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, My problem solved by the following solution

```
 $dql="SELECT c.id, c.name FROM YourBundle:YourTable c  ORDER BY c.id";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql)->getArrayResult();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($query) ; $i++) 
            { 
                $queryArray[$query[$i]['id']]=$query[$i]['name'];
            }
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()

            ->add('colors', 'choice', array('choices' => array( $queryArray)))

            ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation about custom field type and custom templating in [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

I would create a `choice_with_images` custom type that extends the `choice` type and make a custom template for it.

Also, there is a missing quote in your code after the type name `choice`.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried it. But it looks like i need some kind of data transformer for that. But, the field is translating all the data in array of `Color` elements, that gives an error that "Color couldn't be converted to string"

Answer (score 0):

If the colors are an entity in your project then you should be using the entity field type instead.

```
$builder
  ->add('product')
  ->add('colors', 'entity', 
    array(
        'class'    => 'WhateverYourBundle:Color',
        'multiple' => false, 
        'expanded' => true
    )
);
```

If there are only some colors available for the product then you can pass a 'query_builder' option to the array as well. See docs: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Oh, and don't forget to add a __toString() method into your colors entity if there's not one there already.